# Vulkan Building error

Tags: vulkan

I want to build a sample included in Vulkan SDK.

I downloaded the SDK from http://vulkan.lunarg.com and install it.

Then I opened the Visual Studio (I have a 2013 version), I open the solution from this path: (`C:\VulkanSDK\1.0.13.0\Demos`). I choose `DEMOS.sln` file. Then when I click on `LocalWindowsDebugger` this message pops up:

```
vkCreateInstance Failure:
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties failed to find the VK_KHR_surface extention. 
Do you have a compatible Vulkan installable client driver (ICD) insatalled? Please look at the Getting Started  guide for additional information.
```

I have never worked with vulkan, but as it named "Demo", I think that everything inside of it should be set in order to work.

I searched the web, but as it is new, there are few resources talked about it.

What is ICD? and how to install it? (is it different from installer of VulkanSDK?) OR this error is about completely different property? like setting properties of VisualStudio?

Comment: I have no experience with OpenGL too

Comment: Did you check the Getting Started guide as the message suggests?

Comment: @AliBahrami: "*I have no experience with OpenGL too*" Do you have any experience with graphics programming of any kind? Because if not, you probably shouldn't jump into the deep end with Vulkan. All you'll do is run into frustration.

Comment: @NicolBolas: There are opinions on this, but I think it's good to work with brand new technologies with no idea in mind.

Answer (score 6):

ICD is basically your GPU driver...

Both the SDK and driver install **vulkaninfo** app. Use it to determine what extensions you have and whatnot.

BTW Some time ago AMD drivers forgot to export the extensions like VK_KHR_surface. Make sure you are using the latest driver (16.5.2.1 on AMD and 365.19 on NVIDIA as of time of writing).

Also you need supported GPU. Consult:

[NVIDIA supported GPUs](https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver)

[AMD supported GPUs](http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/technologies-gaming/vulkan#sectionThree)

[Khronos maintained list](https://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products)

BTW: All the demos work for me.

Answer (score 4):

> Do you have a compatible Vulkan installable client driver (ICD) installed?

This message tells you that Vulkan's loader wasn't able to find a Vulkan driver on your device. ICD is the installable client driver that comes with the driver of your graphics card.

What GPU are you using and do you have a driver installed that actually supports Vulkan? Note that while your card may support OpenGL it may not support Vulkan.

Comment: I have a nVidia gt 640 that supports vulkan

Comment: Which driver version are you using, and is this the only GPU in your system. It's possible that you use an old driver that doesn't expose the VK_KHR_surface extention which the examples from the SDK require.

Comment: IIRC The main NVidia drivers do not yet support Vulkan; you _must_ download and install the Vulkan compatible drivers.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo : Nope, main line WHQL drivers include Vulkan support too. See e.g. http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/365.19/365.19-win10-win8-win7-winvista-desktop-release-notes-updated.pdf

Comment: @SaschaWillems Hmm. Looks like Vulkan was just included in that driver (it's a "New Feature") and it was released 10 days ago. So in my defense, it's a new thing. OP may just need to upgrade. Glad Vulkan is in mainline now.

Answer (score 2):

Check NVIDIA(performance mode) is selected at "Nvidia X Server Settings" application if you are using ubuntu.